# Different Return Types of `print` and `withFile`

Tags: haskell

Haskell's `withFile` opens a file with a given `IOMode`, and then applies a function `Handle -> IO r`. Ultimately, it returns a type `IO r`.

```
Prelude> import System.IO

Prelude System.IO> :t withFile
withFile :: FilePath -> IOMode -> (Handle -> IO r) -> IO r
```

`print` takes an `a` that derives `Show`, and then returns a type of `IO ()`.

```
Prelude System.IO> :t print
print :: Show a => a -> IO ()
```

What's the significant difference between `IO r` and `IO ()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IO` is a type of kind `* -> *`, which is to say it takes one type argument. In general, an `IO` represents a monadic action which can perform I/O and yield a result. The type argument given to `IO` determines the type of the result. Therefore,

1. **`IO ()` is a monadic action that can perform I/O and yield a `()`.** A `()` has only one value, so it conveys no information. Since it conveys no information, it is often used the same way one might use `void` as a return value in a traditional procedural programming language.
2. **`IO r` is a monadic action that can perform I/O and yield a `r`.** You may notice a similarity to the above statement. The difference is that rather than being a concrete type like `()`, `r` is a *type variable*.

Let me elaborate more on what that means and the consequences of that. Look at the type of `id`:

```
ghci> :t id
id :: a -> a
```

This, of course, means if `id` is given an argument of type `a`, it will return a result of the same type `a`. Now examine the type of `const ()`:

```
ghci> :t const ()
const () :: a -> ()
```

If we give it an `a`, it will return a result of type `()`. Now examine `error`:

```
ghci> :t error
error :: String -> a
```

We have to give it a `String`, but its return value can adapt to whatever we need it to be. Of course, since we can't necessarily construct a value of any given type, that means the only possible definition would be to *never* return a value, which is what `error` does.

So with that understanding, you should realize that while `IO r` always means “a monadic action that can perform I/O and returns a value of type `r`”, the implications of that may vary depending on where it appears in the type signature. Let's look at your particular example:

```
ghci> :t withFile
withFile :: FilePath -> IOMode -> (Handle -> IO r) -> IO r
```

If we had had a function that returned an `IO r` without an `r` appearing anywhere else, the only conclusion we could draw is that the `IO` must never yield a value, or else we wouldn't be able to claim that it could return an arbitrary `r`. Fortunately, that is not the case: another `r` does appear. `withFile` takes a function that returns an `IO r`. Since `withFile` yields an `IO` that creates an `r`, and the only way it knows how to create an `r` is through the function we gave it, we know that if it's going to terminate, it has to execute the function we gave it at least once. Furthermore, we know that it's going to have to return one of the `r`s it got from that.

So, in the context of `withFile`, `IO r` means that if you give it a function that yields a monadic action that returns some specific type, `withFile` will end up giving you a monadic action that yields that type, too. As a concrete example:

```
myInt <- withFile "number.txt" ReadMode (fmap read . hGetContents)
print (myInt + (1 :: Int))
```

`hGetContents`, given a `Handle`, will return an `IO String`. The `fmap read` will turn that into an `IO Int`. Since `withFile` was defined using a type variable, not specifying any particular concrete type, it will adapt to the type we gave it (`Handle -> IO Int`) and return an `IO Int`. Then we can use `<-` within a block of `do` notation to execute it and bind `myInt` to the result. The return value bubbled through the `withFile`.

Comment: That `myInt` snippet has no type annotation for the read, so without more context it will probably default to `Integer` rather than `Int`. Or worse, if you try to put it into GHCi so that the lines are inferred separately, then the first line will default to reading a `()` and the second line will give an error.

Comment: How do you know that `The fmap read will turn that into an IO Int.`? Does Haskell's `read` know how to read the contents as an `Int` (or `Integer`)?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: Oops, you're right! I meant to annotate the `1` literal to explicitly be an `Int`. Your point about GHCi still stands, though.

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, `read` is part of the `Read` typeclass, so `read` knows how to read the contents of any instance of that class. Since there is an instance of `Read` for `Int`, `read` knows how to read it.

Answer (score 2):

`IO r` means that after executing the action with a side effect, it will contain some value `r` in it.

`IO` actions that has a result type of `()` can be compared to `void` in other languages. (Actually it is an empty tuple `()` whose type is also `()`).

The difference between `IO r` and `IO ()` is that in the second case after executing the action with side effects, it doesn't contain any value inside it. This indicates that you are executing the `IO` action for the sole purpose of it's side effect like printing to the screen. Whereas in `IO r`, after executing the action with a side effect it also contains some value wrapped in `IO` which can be subsequently used in your program.

---

Even `withFile` function can return `IO ()` since `r` is just a more general form of `()`, depending upon the type of higher order function passed to it:

```
test = withFile "testFile" ReadMode (\handle ->
                                           do
                                             str <- hGetContents handle
                                             print str
                                           )
```

Inspecting its type:

```
ghci> :t test
test :: IO ()
```

Answer (score 0):

`IO r` is a more general type then `IO ()`.

`r` is a variable and could be any type.

If `r == ()`, then `IO r == IO ()`